# How to select the 1st value from duplicate values in multi-table join

Tags: sql, sql-server

I'm trying to write a SQL query to return the first value based on an order by for a date column where duplicates are returned but I am getting one returned row overall (I'm trying to use `Select Top 1`, just incorrectly)
Here's the query just to get all rows, duplicates included:

```
SELECT u.userid, Table1.Col1, Table1.Col2, Table1.Col3
FROM Table1
JOIN Table2 ON Table2.PK = Table1.FK
JOIN [User] u ON Table2.UserId = u.UserId
WHERE u.UserId IN (2,4,6,7,10,11,12,8,5)
ORDER BY Table1.Date DESC
```

Each `User` is associated with multiple records in `Table1`, but I want just the first returned `Table1` columns for a `User` based on the most recent `Table1.Date` value. I'm assuming I need a subquery, I just don't know to properly construct it and any help is appreciated.

The above query shows current data (top 4 shown below for ease):

| userid | col 1 | col 2 | col 3 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 3 | 2021 | null |
| 1 | 4 | 2022 | null |
| 2 | 5 | 2021 | null |
| 2 | 6 | 2022 | null |

I would like to return only the 2nd and 4th rows as those are the first column values associated with the users (users 1 and 2 here) and have the greatest date (in col 2, from the ORDER BY at the end of the above query).

Comment: Look into `row_number()` function.

Comment: Can you update your post with sample input data and expected output?

Comment: @lemon Updating now, knew I forgot something lol.

Comment: I've never typed a table in SO, but I followed the guidelines and it looked like a normal table in review, but after posting it looks like mashed together pipes and words. Do yall see the same?

Comment: You just need to add a line break before the table to fix that.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `top(1)` if you refactor your query to use *apply()*

Something like the following:

```
select u.userid, t.*
from [User] u
cross apply (
  select top(1) t1.col1, t1.col2, t1.col3
  from table2 t2
  join table1 t1 on t1.fk = t2.pk
  where t2.userid = u.userid
  order by t1.date desc
)t
where u.UserId in (2,4,6,7,10,11,12,8,5);
```

Comment: That did it, thank you so much! I've never heard of cross apply, so I learned another new item as well :)

Comment: This is SQL Server's implementation of a *lateral join*, it's been in the product since 2005 but often overlooked!